# Logos are Overlapping When Window Size Is Smaller or on Mobile/Tablet?

Tags: css, overlap

I am in charge of our company website and am a little bit stumped right now.

The website url is:

https://nutiva.com/

If you change the size of the window you will notice there are two logos that over lap when changing the width of the screen or when viewing on a tablet/mobile device.

I want to keep the logo that says "Nuture Vitality" and remove the other.

Any ideas/recommendations are appreciated?

Comment: Please make the question self-contained, external links tend to change and make the question nonsense for general use. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: To expand on what Imre said once you've gotten an answer and fixed your website the question will be about something that people can no longer see. The goal here is to both answer your question, but also to have the resulting question and answer pair be useful for folks that come across it by searching to solve their own similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

This media query is displaying the image which you want to remove.

Just give `background:none;` and it will hide your image.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px)
 #title-area{
    background:none;
}
```